# Chain rule with intermediate vector function

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, chain-rule

Imagine we have two functions: $f:R^n \to R$, and $g: R \to R^n$. We want to differentiate their composition: $f(g(x))$. I want to do it in the matrix form. If I do so naively, I get nonsense:
$$
\frac{\partial f(g(x))}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
$$
The first one is a row vector, the second is also a row vector. We can't multiply them. Where's the mistake? How is it possible to fix it?

Comment: It should just be $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{d g_i(t)}{dt} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$$

Comment: But the rule should be applicable to matrices which both derivative are ($n \times 1$). How would it work there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $g:\>{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}^n$ the matrix $[dg(t)]$ is a column vector, and for $f:\>{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}$ the matrix $[df(x)]$ is a row vector. It follows that the composed map $\phi:=f\circ g:\>{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ has derivative $d\phi(t)=df\bigl(g(t)\bigr)\circ dg(t)$
with $1\times1$-matrix
$$[\phi'(t)]=\bigl[df\bigl(g(t)\bigr)\bigr]\,[dg(t)]\ ,$$
which works perfectly well in matrix terms.

Comment: I mixed all the stuff up, because I wanted to use it for DL which have their own conventions (they use the derivative of the same shape as what we differentiate by). If we use Jacobians, everything is fine.

Answer (score 2):

The correct formula is
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{d(f\circ g)(x)}{dx}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v_{i}}(g(x))\dfrac{dg_{i}(x)}{dx},
\end{align*}
where $g=(g_{1},...,g_{n})$.

Comment: So, basically, you transposed one of the matrices, and used matrix multiplication. But why it work this way in this case but doesn't work when both $f$ and $g$ are multivariate functions.

Comment: For $g=(g_{1},...,g_{n})$ which each $g_{i}:{\bf{R}}^{m}\rightarrow{\bf{R}}$, then $\dfrac{\partial(f\circ g)(x)}{\partial x_{i}}=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v_{j}}(g(x))\dfrac{\partial g_{j}(x)}{\partial x_{i}}$.

Comment: The general formula is that $D(f\circ g)(x)=Df(g(x))Dg(x)$ in the sense of Jacobian matrices, when you do the expansion, you know the reason why it has to behave like that way immediately.